# SSH backup via PHP problem

Tags: php, ssh, backup

I am trying to backup all the files on our server using some SSH commands via PHP and I have a script working to some extent.

The problem is that only some of the folders actually contain any files but the folder structure seems to be correct though.

This is the script I am using:

```
<?php
   $output = `cd /
   ls -al
   tar -cf /home/b/a/backup/web/public_html/archive.tar home/*`;

   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I cant even view the files via SSH commands, an example of this is the test account. If I use the following command I am unable to view the website files.

```
<?php
   $output = `cd /home/t/e/test/
   ls -alRh`;

   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

But if I use the same commands on the a different account I am able to see and download of the website files.

Is this a permission problem or am I missing something in my script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -l / | grep home
```

the output will be like this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel        8 Mar 30 14:13 home -> usr/home
```

In my case, the owner is **root**, and the **root** user its primary group is **wheel**, so now we add **www-data** user to **wheel** group so he can list files in there:

```
usermod -a -G wheel www-data
```

You can download some files because they located in directory owned by **www-data** user, and when you can't, www-data has no permission in that.

Comment: `ls -l / | grep home` returns `drwxr-xr-x  28 root  root   4096 May  2  2010 home` does this mean I need to run `usermod -a -G root www-data`?

Comment: @James, if you never give it  try, you will never know it :D.

Comment: Tried and it didn't make any difference! I still can only see the files inside some of the folders!

Comment: Do you run your script from browser?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't have SSH access so I have to run the commands via PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think it permission problem, try to give apache user(or what you set it) permission to read `/home/*` directory's.
To find the user name that used by apache service run this:
For linux:

```
egrep -iw --color=auto 'user|group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

For FreeBSD:

```
egrep -iw --color=auto '^user|^group' /usr/local/etc/apache22/httpd.conf
```

Comment: I have tried the following and could only find an apache2.conf file within the etc/ folder. That returned the following: `User www-data` 
`Group www-data`

Comment: In your case, apaceh use www-data as user and group, try now to give www-data user permission to read content from /home/*

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean by this comment, I am very new to SSH and apache commands. Also I am confused as to why I can download some files but not others?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that PHP is running in a chroot.

If you just want to execute a backup, consider doing it in a different language. Especially if it is just a sequence of UNIX commands, write a shell script. Perhaps more details on what this script will be used for and who is providing and maintaining your hosting will be useful.